# Is asking the same question additionally asking for the optimal way considered a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

If there is a question that asks

> How to do X?

which already has some answers, but then someone asks

> What is the optimal way of doing X?

is the question seeking for the optimal way considered a duplicate?

Comment: If not dupe, very likely primarily opinion based.

Comment: I would not only see that as a duplicate, but also as being too broad and opinion based. "The best way" is usually not answerable because it heavily depends on outside factors.

Comment: @l4mpi there is a big difference between "The best way" and "The optimal way"

Comment: @Vencovsky I don't see any except for semantics. Perhaps you could elaborate what you mean with "optimal"? Also, with any piece of code there are various things you could optimize for, some of which are diametrally opposed.

Comment: What is, "best"?  Why is it better than this other solution over here?  In this case, optimal is synonymous with best.  Either way, though, it's asking the same thing.

Comment: @l4mpi Optimal would be like if you could do it in `O(N log N)` or `O(log N)`. I could also be something like "fastest way".

Comment: If instead of the missleading "optimal", it said "fastest way considereing `O` notation, would that be a duplicate?

Comment: @Vencovsky ok, so your question is about performance of the code. In that case, while that does still heavily depend on the specifics (e.g. which language and db are you using in which environment), you could end up with an answerable question if you narrow it down enough.

Comment: And if it's literally about O notation - as in, algorithmic performance as opposed to real world code performance - you might be better off asking on the CS.SE site.

Comment: @l4mpi It doesn't heavily depend on the specifics, but it depends on the algorithm you use. Time is not the point, if your computer is fast or slow, doesn't matter when you consider `O` notation.

Comment: Then instead of phrasing your question "optimal way of doing X", be more specific. Say *"this code here solves X, but is inefficient in these dimensions (e.g. complexity, space efficiency, etc.), how can this be improved?"* Otherwise, why shouldn't the existing duplicate solution already be the optimal one?

Comment: @deceze so to not be a duplicate, it would need to explain why the current answer isn't enough?

Comment: Yes. If you can clearly delineate your question from an existing one, it's a different question. Otherwise it just sounds like the same question phrased differently. By default I'd assume accepted answers to be as close to optimal as possible anyway, so if that doesn't meet your standards, you need to be a bit more detailed about those standards.

Comment: @Vencovsky it feels like it is more of a theoretical question (because otherwise, you _should_ be interested in the real world performance and not in O notation - an `O(log N)` solution with a constant factor of 10^10000 would not be preferable to a `O(N log N)` solution with a factor of 2). If that's the case I would recommend that you try asking about the algorithm on [the computerscience SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) which might give you better answers than StackOverflow.

Comment: @deceze thanks, that make it much more clear

Comment: @Vencovsky Remember that your explanation *needs to be convincing to the community*. The community could still disagree with you and vote to close as duplicate. Also, I'm with l4mpi: your question seems to be more about theory and would probably be better suited for CS.SE.

Comment: @l4mpi thanks too, O notation questions would probably be better in the cs.se than stackoverflow

Comment: If it's working code you are perhaps looking for a review?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question

> What's the optimal way of doing 'X'?

Is opinion based and not clear. You have to state what do you mean by optimal in terms of performance, execution time, etc.

Asking it on StackOverflow will generate different varieties of answers and *mostly* opinion-based.

But,

for doing a certain work, **people upvote the most optimal** way and the best answers rise to the top eventually. If the most optimal way of doing "X" is answered already on "How to do X?" Then this means that there is no more optimal way of doing "X" then "What is the optimal way of doing X?" is a dupe of "How to do X?"

Comment: Are you from Code Review?  Because asking for the "optimal way" without providing criteria for determining what is "optimal" is "Too Broad" everywhere, even on Code Review.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you are right. Edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ask for an optimal way, you must specify a measure that is to be optimized. Usually that will be a combination of execution speed, code size, memory consumption or other stuff, but it's not clear *a priori* what is meant by optimal. Without a proper definition such questions must be put on hold as unclear until such a definition is added.

Sometimes even with a given definition of "optimal way", the difference between "How to do X?" and "How to do X in this specific optimal way?" might still be very small, because people even without being asked for explicitly tend to give optimized solutions in answers and especially if the answers to both questions are the same, people might still be tempted to close the latter as a duplicate of the former. If you disagree, it's then very important to argue why the solutions to "How to do X?" might not be optimal in the sense of "How to do X in this specific optimal way?".

As a general guide if you want to ask "How to do X in an optimal way?":

- Make sure you included your definition of optimal.
- Check if a question "How to do X?" already exists and if it does, include a description why the solutions of this questions are not optimal for you.